# Impossible constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

So I have this code :

```
class A{
public:
    A(){}
    A(int){}
};
int main(){
    A x;//I want this to give me error
    A x(1);//or this to give me error
return 0;
}
```

How to make the class to be impossible to be constructed? without changing visibility of the constructors;

Comment: Why do you want  a type that cannot be instantiated at all? That hardly sounds useful.

Comment: But A x(1); still works , yes something that cannot be instatiated

Comment: I'm not a C++ expert and may miss something but why not throw an exception inside the constructor ? Isn't it what OP means by 'give me an error' ?

Comment: @Ciomegu then `A(int) = delete;` as well

Comment: @Ciomegu you need to think outside the box and extrapolate the idea presented by Piotr to the other constructor as well.

Comment: Ok ok , but is there any other way? I understood this only works in c++ 11 but what about other versions

Comment: @Ciomegu if your question is about an older standard, please add its tag ([c++98], [c++03] or [c++11]) to the question.

Comment: @Ciomegu the way to do it in earlier standard versions was to declare the constructors private.

Answer (score 5):

You could remove the user-defined constructor, and make the default constructor [deleted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions) (since C++11).

```
class A{
public:
    A() = delete;
};
```

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: @Ciomegu The pre-C++11 way is make constructors private and don't define them. But you said don't want to change visibility...

Comment: I actually found out, make something virtual then equal to 0;Thank you

Comment: @Ciomegu: You're talking about pure virtual functions. This does not apply to class constructors. Pure virtual functions will actually force derived classes to implement the function after all.